# Various deletion methods for a doubly linked list not working (java)(deleteEven(); deleteMultiple())

Tags: java, linked-list, abstract, doubly-linked-list

I am practicing on new methods to delete elements in a doubly linked list.
I implemented a method `deleteEven()` that deletes all even values from the list, `deleteHigher(int value)` that delete all values in the list that are greater than the value in the argument, `deleteMultiple(int value)` that deletes all values from the list that are multiple of a given value in the argument.

I am not getting errors, it's just that not all the desired values are being deleted.
Any help is appreciated. (I'm still new to programing)

This is my code:

```
public class List {

    class Element{
        int data;
        Element next;
        Element previous;
        
        Element(int value){
            this.data = value;
            this.next = null;
            this.previous = null;
        }
    }
    
    
    private Element head;
    private Element rear;
    
    
    public List() {
        this.head = null;
        this.rear = null;
    }
    
    public List(List a) {
        this();
        if(a.head == null)
            return;
        
        Element cur = a.head;
        Element tmp = new Element(cur.data);
        
        head = rear = tmp;
        cur = cur.next;
        
        while(cur != null) {
            tmp = new Element(cur.data);
            rear.next = tmp;
            tmp.previous = rear;
            rear = tmp;
            cur = cur.next;
        }
    }
    
    
    public List List1(List list, int value) {
        Element cur = list.head;
        List a = new List();
        
        if(list.head == null)
            return a;
        
        while(cur != null) {
            if(list.head.data < value)
                a.insert(list.head.data);
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        return a;
    }
    
    
    public String toString() {  
        String str;
        Element cur = this.head;
        
        if(this.head == null)
            str = "The linked list is empty";
        else {
            str = "The linked list contains ";
            while(cur != null) {
                str += cur.data + " | ";
                cur = cur.next;
            }
        }       
        return str; 
    }
    
    
    public int getLength() {
        Element cur = this.head;
        int c = 0;
        
        if(this.head == null)
            return 0;
        
        while(cur != null) {
            c++;
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        return c;
    }
    
    
    public int countOdd() {
        Element cur = this.head;
        int c = 0;
        
        if(this.head == null)
            return 0;
        
        while(cur != null) {
            if(cur.data % 2 != 0)
                c++;
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        return c;
    }
    
    
    public boolean insert(int value) {
        Element tmp = new Element(value);
        Element cur = this.head;
        
        if(this.isInList(value))
            return false;
        
        if(this.head == null) {
            this.head = this.rear = tmp;
            return true;
        }
        
        if(this.head.data < value) {
            tmp.next = this.head;
            this.head.previous = tmp;
            this.head = tmp;
            return true;
        }
        
        if(this.rear.data > value) {
            tmp.previous = this.rear;
            this.rear.next = tmp;
            this.rear = tmp;
            return true;
        }
        
        while(cur.next != null && cur.next.data > value) {
            
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        
        if(cur.data == tmp.data)
            return false;
        
        tmp.next = cur.next;
        tmp.previous = cur;
        cur.next.previous = tmp;
        cur.next = tmp;
        return true;
    }
    
    
    public boolean isInList(int value) {
        Element cur = this.head;
        
        if(this.head == null)
            return false;
        
        while(cur != null) {
            if(cur.data == value)
                return true;
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    
    public List inter(List a, List b) {
        Element curA = a.head;
        List c = new List();
        
        if(a.head == null || b.head == null)
            return c;
        
        while(curA != null ) {
            if(b.isInList(curA.data))
                c.insert(curA.data);
            curA = curA.next;
        }
        return c;
    }
    
    
    public List union(List a, List b) {
        Element curA = a.head;
        Element curB = b.head;
        List c = new List();
        
        while(curA != null && curB != null) {
            if(curA.data > curB.data) {
                c.insert(curA.data);
                curA = curA.next;
            }else {
                c.insert(curB.data);
                curB = curB.next;
            }       
        }
        
        while(curA != null) {
            c.insert(curA.data);
            curA = curA.next;
        }
        
        while(curB != null) {
            c.insert(curB.data);
            curB = curB.next;
        }
        return c;
    }
    
    
    public int findLastOccurence(int value) {
        Element cur = this.head;
        int length = this.getLength() - 1;
        
        if(this.head == null)
            return -100;
        
        while(cur != null) {
            if(cur.data == value)
                length--;
            cur = cur.previous;
        }
        return length;
    }
    
    
    public void deleteEven() {
        Element cur = this.head;
        
        //empty list
        if(this.head == null)
            return;
        
        //deleting the head
        while(this.head != null && this.head.data % 2 == 0) {
            this.head = this.head.next;
        
        //case of if after deleting the head, the list becomes empty
        if(this.head == null) 
            this.rear = null;
        else 
            this.head.previous = null;
            return;
        }
            
        while(this.rear != null && this.rear.data % 2 == 0) {
            this.rear = this.rear.previous;
            this.rear.next = null;
        }
        
        while(cur != null ) {
            if(cur.data % 2 == 0) {
                cur.previous.next = cur.next;
                cur.next.previous = cur.previous;
            }
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        
        if ((cur == null) )
            return;
    }
    
    
    public boolean deleteHigher(int value) {
        Element cur = this.head;
        
        if(this.head == null)
            return false;
        
        while(this.head != null && this.head.data > value) {
            this.head = this.head.next;
        }
        
        if(this.head == null) {
            this.rear = null;
            return true;
        }else {
            this.head.previous = null;
        }
            
        while(this.rear != null && this.rear.data > value)
            this.rear = this.rear.previous;
        
        while(cur != null && cur.data < value) {            
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        
        if ((cur == null) || (cur.data != value))
            return false;
        
        cur.previous.next = cur.next;
        cur.next.previous = cur.previous;
        
        return true;
    }
    
    
    public void deleteMultipleOf(int value) {
        Element cur = this.head;
        
        if(this.head == null)
            return ;
        
        //case of deleting the head
        while(this.head != null && this.head.data % value == 0) {
            this.head = this.head.next;     
        
        //case of if the head is deleted, the list becomes empty
        if(this.head == null) 
            this.rear = null;
        else 
            this.head.previous = null;
        }
        
        //case of deleting the rear
        while(this.rear != null && this.rear.data % value == 0) {
            this.rear = this.rear.previous;
        }
        
        while(cur != null && cur.data % value != 0) 
            cur = cur.next;
        
        if(cur == null || cur.data % value != 0)
            return ;
        
        cur.next.previous = cur.previous;
        cur.previous.next = cur.next;

    }
    
    
    public void deleteLAstOccurence(int value) {
        Element cur = this.head;
        
        if(this.head == null)
            return ;
        
        while(cur != null) {
            if(cur.data == value) {
                cur.next.previous = cur.previous;
                cur.previous.next = cur.next;
                 
            }
            cur = cur.previous;
        }
    }
    
    
    public void deleteAllOccurences(int value) {
        Element cur = this.head;
        
        //deleting head
        while(cur != null && cur.data == value) {
            cur.next = this.head;
            cur.next.previous = null;
            cur = this.head;
        }
        
        while(cur != null) {
            while(cur != null && cur.data != value) {
                cur = cur.next;
            }
            if(cur == null)
                return;
            
            cur.next.previous = cur.previous;
            cur.previous.next = cur.next;
        }
    }
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List l = new List();
        List l1 = new List();
//      List l2 = new List();
//      List l3 = new List();

        l.insert(2);
        l.insert(4);
        l.insert(6);
        l.insert(7);
        l.insert(3);
        l.insert(2);
        System.out.println(l);
        
        l1.insert(4);
        l1.insert(6);
        l1.insert(7);
        l1.insert(0);
        l1.insert(10);
//      System.out.println(l1);
//      
//      System.out.println(l.isInList(6));      
//      
//      System.out.println(l2.inter(l,  l1));
//      
//      System.out.println(l3.union(l, l1));
        
//      l.deleteEven();        //not everything is being deleted
//      System.out.println(l);
    
//      l.deleteHigher(2);    //working
//      System.out.println(l);
        
        l.deleteMultipleOf(2); // not working
        System.out.println(l);
        
//      l.deleteLAstOccurence(3);// not working
//      System.out.println(l);
        
//      System.out.println(l.findLastOccurence(-1));
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem of deleteEven(), deleteHigher(int value), deleteMultiple(int value) is that they break at a first value meant to be delete. Like ` this.head.data % 2 == 0` condition commands loop the break if it meets uneven integer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's probably a good time learning how to debug. You can either use an actual debugger or even just throw in print statements everywhere to see what's going on. Then you can get to at least the cause of the problem much faster, even if you can't solve it.

Comment: @HenryTwist To be totally honest with you, programming isn't my main thing, but it's a course that I'm forced to take so I can graduate, and debugging isn't in my course material and I will never use this course again, I just want to pass it, so If it is possible to help me where the problem is, I will be very grateful.

Comment: @bimjhi I took your hint and tried to implement it, it worked for the ```deleteEven()``` method, but did not on the ```deleteMultiple(int value)```

Comment: That's generally not how this site works. Most of us want to help people who actually want help, not someone to do their work for them. However it seems like @bimjhi wants to help regardless, so hopefully they can fix your problem!

Comment: I'm not asking you to do my job, some hints would be great as @bimjhi did.

Comment: I did give a hint, print out the progress of the algorithm at each step and find the inconsistency. Then hopefully either the problem will become obvious or you can ask us here.

Comment: @HenryTwist but I already printed before posting my question and I didn't get what is wrong.

Comment: Well, it's too complicated for one question and a debugger seemingly needed. I managed to make deleteMultipleOf(2)  to delete all numbers but 2 by modifying its last loop to `while(cur != null) { if (cur.data % value == 0) { cur.next.previous = cur.previous;
 cur.previous.next = cur.next;}` Then it throws an exception when processing 2. Basically, no need to multiple numbers, only `l.insert(2);` is enough. So I recommend you to modify the question as follows: delete all but code *essentially* needed by deleteMultipleOf and ask why exception is thrown after `l.insert(2);l.deleteMultipleOf(2);`

Answer (score 1):

```
public void deleteEven() {
        
        //empty list
        if(this.head == null)
            return;
        
        //deleting the head
        while(this.head != null && this.head.data % 2 == 0) 
            this.head = this.head.next;
            
        
        //case of if after deleting the head, the list becomes empty
        if(this.head == null) {
            this.rear = null;
        }else 
            this.head.previous = null;          
        
            
        while(this.rear != null && this.rear.data % 2 == 0) {
            this.rear = this.rear.previous;
            this.rear.next = null;
        }
        
        Element cur = this.head;
        while(cur.next != null ) {
            if(cur.next.data % 2 == 0) {
                cur.next = cur.next.next;
                cur.next.previous = cur;
            }else 
            cur = cur.next;
        }
    }
    
    
    public boolean deleteHigher(int value) {
        
        if(this.head == null)
            return false;
        
        while(this.head != null && this.head.data > value) {
            this.head = this.head.next;
        }
        
        if(this.head == null) {
            this.rear = null;
            return true;
        }else {
            this.head.previous = null;
        }
            
        while(this.rear != null && this.rear.data > value)
            this.rear = this.rear.previous;
        
        Element cur = this.head;
        while(cur.next != null) {
            if(cur.next.data > value) {
                cur.next = cur.next.next;
                cur.next.previous = cur;
            }else
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    
    public void deleteMultipleOf(int value) {       
        if(this.head == null)
            return ;
        
        //case of deleting the head
        while(this.head != null && this.head.data % value == 0) 
            this.head = this.head.next;     
        
        //case of if the head is deleted, the list becomes empty
        if(this.head == null) {
            this.rear = null;
        }else 
            this.head.previous = null;
                
        //case of deleting the rear
        while(this.rear != null && this.rear.data % value == 0) {
            this.rear = this.rear.previous;
        }
```